# electron-winstaller throws The system cannot find the path specified. at Squirrel.Utility.<CreateZipFromDirectory>d__23.MoveNext()<---

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to build a electron installer for windows platform in `Azure DevOps`. I have successfully ran the electron-package command with npm run build (look at my `package.json`). After that when I try to run the command to create the RELEASES, .msi, .exe and .nupkg files with `electron-winstaller` it throws an error saying:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>      at Squirrel.Utility.d__23.MoveNext()<---

The command that I executed was `npm run create-installer-win` which executes the command `node build.js`.

The build runs in a on-premises agent with windows server 2014.

Locally everything works fine.

[Image of my build.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qERR.png)

[Image of my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVodk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vrwn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The was with Squirrel.

My agent is running with NT AUTHORITY\System user which does not have permission to create the SquirrelTemp folder in %appdata%. When it try to create de folder in current folder it throws the error because it does not find the SquirrelTemp folder.

The solution I have found was to set a environment variable SQUIRREL_TEMP in the build pipeline with the value to %currentfolder%\SquirrelTemp and it works.

Thanks to https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/1081#issuecomment-340958128